# How to run python playwright on Azure Cloud using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cloud-services, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to deploy timer trigger function that extracts data from web. I'm using playwright to access. My code runs as expected on my local machine. However when I tried to deploy on cloud it says:

`Result: Failure Exception: Exception: ================================================================================ "chromium" browser was not found. Please complete Playwright installation via running "python -m playwright install" ================================================================================ Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 353, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await fi.func(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/AsyncFlight/__init__.py", line 21, in main browser = await p.chromium.launch() File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 9943, in launch raise e File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 9921, in launch await self._impl_obj.launch( File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_type.py", line 73, in launch raise not_installed_error(f'"{self.name}" browser was not found.')`

I have checked my consumption plan and my os on cloud is Linux and`"azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment"` is set  to true.
I have included playwright in my requirements.txt. Don't know what I'm missing. Please help!!

Thankyou

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what the error instructs you to do:
`Please complete Playwright installation via running "python -m playwright install"`

Comment: how should i do that on azure cloud. i tried including it in requirements.txt but does not work

Comment: Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#package-management

Comment: thank you for the help, but the solution does not seem to work. it keeps giving me same error